# Debian create persistent network bridge

Tags: networking, debian, linux-networking, bridge, libvirt

I need to create a persistent network bridge for Virtual machines (`libvirt`)

So this bridge does not need any physical ports, connections will be routed for this bridge.

If I set this up manually, it works as I described. However I can't get this to persist between reboots.

I have created the bridge in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
 auto vm-bridge
  iface vm-bridge inet static
   address 10.1.0.1
   broadcast 10.1.0.3
   netmask 255.255.255.252
   gateway 10.1.0.1
```

However the interface is not created when the host reboots. All reference on the internet are adding `bridge_ports` to the bridge, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give an option so the bridge plugin that is provided as `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge` by installing the package `bridge-utils` activates. The main command it provides `brctl` is of no use (superseded by `ip link` + `bridge`), but the plugin does matter. Without a bridge-related option, the system has no way to understand a bridge has to be created. So if using the package `ifupdown` (rather than `ifupdown2` or `ifupdown-ng`):

```
apt install bridge-utils
```

Then the simplest option for this is to tell it there is no bridge port. Add this option:

```
bridge_ports none
```

which will now activate the plugin and create a bridge and as requested with the special keyword `none` will not attach any interface as bridge port to it.

Remarks:

- there is *one* default route to be used at the same time

  > ```
  >   gateway 10.1.0.1
  > ```

  is probably a mistake: if you already have an other default route on the system (also with metric 0), this will make the result fail. This is especially true when designating oneself as the gateway. Remove it first (as I did below), and ponder adding it again later.
- a bridge without bridge port is in operstate DOWN

  ... on any recent system running a recent *systemd* such as Debian 11 or 12.

  As described for example in this [Q/A](https://serverfault.com/questions/1062421/linux-ipv6-bridge-address-does-not-work-when-mac-address-is-forced) with the cause described for example in my [answer in this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719379/how-can-i-make-linux-generate-different-mac-addresses-for-different-bridge-devic/719391#719391). This can cause a few issues for IPv6, but usually none for IPv4.

The configuration becomes:

```
auto vm-bridge
iface vm-bridge inet static
   address 10.1.0.1
   broadcast 10.1.0.3
   netmask 255.255.255.252
   # gateway 10.1.0.1
   bridge_ports none
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that `bridge-utils` is already installed. I will try your solution and report back!

Comment: Thank you it worked. You were also right about the `gateway`, it is not needed.

Comment: `bridge-utils` is **obsolete** and not needed anymore. `iproute2` long time took its role in configuring bridges, and Debian uses it since version 10, AFAIK.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov the package `bridge-utils` is not used for providing `brctl` here, it's used for the *plugin* it provides to `ifupdown` (as `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge`) so it can configure a (simple) bridge without using `pre-up`. We don't care if the plugin uses `bridge`, `brctl` or (as actually the case) a mix of `brctl` and `ip link`. That's the same as telling: `ebtables` is obsolete, it has been superseded by `nftables`: people still use it today. Beside I already wrote it: "The main command it provides brctl is of no use (superseded by ip link + bridge)".

Comment: `bridge` program is also the part of `iproute2`. `bridge-utils` package is not needed *at all*, it is completely redundant. All internal "plugins" to configure bridges use `ip link add type bridge` subcommand to create bridges and `ip link set master` to enslave interfaces since Debian 10. E.g. for example, I'm sitting at Debian 11 machine now, I have bridge and tap in the `interfaces` file and no `bridge-utils` or `tunctl` is installed.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov testing on Debian 12: with the package `ifupdown` (not to be confused with the different package `ifupdown2` nor `ifupdown-ng`) I can bring a bridge br0 up (that does not exist before typing `ifup br0`) only when the package `bridge-utils` is also installed, else I get `Cannot find device "br0"`). I suspect you are not using the package `ifupdown` but an other variant. Or that the bridge was already configured outside of this package, or using `pre-up`.

Comment: Well, yes, it seems ifupdown2 does it differently. I never noticed the difference since I mostly used Proxmox which brings ifupdown2 since I don't remember when and has out of the box bridge support with vlans and whatever else for obvious reasons. Now I'm curious why Debian uses iproute2 for most things (e.g. ip addresses, tunnels, vlans and bonds) and doesn't use it just for bridges by default.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov at last. Please reread carefully my question: there's written "So if using the package ifupdown (rather than ifupdown2 or ifupdown-ng)". What should be done by Debian (but doesn't have any urgency): split bridge-utils into two packages: one for (obsolete) brctl, and one for ifupdown plugin. Then update the plugin to use only bridge and no more brctl. Then in a future Debian have bridge-utils become a meta package depending on the formers for ease of dist upgrade, have ifupdown depend on the split plugin package. etc. Until then, there's no real interest of changing it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as commenters pointed out this answer is based on specific version of Debian Bookworm from cloud image. For the usual version of Debian other answer holds.

Assuming you are using Debian Bookworm, it doesn't obey `/etc/network/interfaces` anymore by default, since it uses `systemd-networkd`.

To create bridge add file `vm-bridge.netdev` to `/etc/systemd/network/`:

```
[NetDev]
Name=vm-bridge
Kind=bridge
```

Now we need to configure network for this bridge. Create file `/etc/systemd/network/vm-bridge.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=vm-bridge

[Network]
Address=10.1.0.1/30
Gateway=10.1.0.1
```

And then restart networkd:

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Refer to [docs](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdNetworkd#setting_up_a_network_bridge) for more information. For specific configuration there is detailed guide on [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd#Network_bridge_with_static_IP_addresses).

Comment: As long as Debian provides ifupdown (or equivalent) and it's installed, it will obey /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: @A.B ifupdown is not installed by default on Debian Bookworm. Native way to handle network devices today is via networkd.

Comment: Looking at /var/log/installer/ in Debian 12 (bookworm), ifupdown does get installed by default.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I am using debian cloud image in container, which is missing it, you are correct.

Comment: Yes, I know about `system-networkd`, but I'm always confused about this, mainly because as you said, `interfaces` still work. If anyone knows any simple solution on how to check which one is used, I will be happy. Checking `systemctl status systemd-networkd` shows as `inactive`

Comment: Systemd-network is only used when specifically forced. Debian is conservative when it comes to this point. I suggest that you update the answer and provide a hint. Debian is mostly not like Ubuntu. In short, Debian will use /etc/network/interfaces for a decade. This file is still used today in a fresh downloaded Debian Bookworm ISO from debian.org.